# How many triangles in the following figure?

Tags: geometry, triangles

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azXGw.jpg)

There is trapezium ABCD

• AE is perpendicular to DC

• BF is perpendicular to DC

• lines are drawn through point A to C, B to D , A to F , B to E.

• Those lines intersect at varius points in the figure

*The description of figure is given in case of need to redraw it*

The question is how many triangles are being made inside the figure

Also is there any quick way to find,calculate or count them?

Answer (score 0):

Note that it is a hexagon and all vertices are connected by edges (though some lie atop each other and don't count as triangles, due to not satisfying $a+b>c$ for all cyclic shifts of edge lengths). The number of triangles in a connected graph on $n$ nodes are the number of ordered $3$-tuples from it, $n\choose3$, so in this case ${6\choose3}=20$. Then note that of these, the ${4\choose3}=4$ $3$-tuples from the $4$ vertices $C,D,E,F$ are excluded, so there are $20-4=16$ triangles.

Comment: You might want to include triangles involving $O$ and the other intersection point. (Not immediately clear to me if that's OP's intention.)